# Number 0 not work with if statement inside while loop php

Tags: php

i want check a quantities from all in table Pharmacy

if the quantity == 0 make update and change "Out Stock"

else the quantity will be change to "In Stock"

when get number 0 if statement not work.

this my php code:

```
 $select="SELECT * FROM drugs WHERE quantity";
$resultt = mysqli_query($connect, $select);

$count="1";

while($row = $resultt->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $id=$row["id"]; 
    $Quantity=$row["quantity"]; 

if($Quantity == "0"){
$update="UPDATE drugs SET stock='Out Stock' WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $update);   

}else{
$update="UPDATE drugs SET stock='In Stock' WHERE id='$id'";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $update);

}


    $count++;
    $Q+=$Quantity;


}
```

thanks

Comment: What's the datatype of column `quantity`?

Comment: What does "not work" mean? Any errors?

Comment: If you're basing that off the quantity that's already in the table you don't need to do anything at all. Just use the quantity field when you're displaying things later.

Comment: What is the data type of the quantity attribute in the database?

Comment: why these are $count++; $Q+=$Quantity;

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php apply that to your query, and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to your php.

Comment: $count++; it is counter

Comment: $Q+=$Quantity; Calculate the total

Comment: don't use varchar for integers. You have answers below, ask them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother.

You're setting one value based on another in the same row. There's no need to do that. The table design is just duplicating the existing data into two representations.

If the end goal is just to output stuff to users, do that in the view.

```
if ($row['quantity'] < 1) {
  echo "out of stock!";
}
```

If you really want to update the database, do it in two queries instead of 2 per individual row:

```
UPDATE drugs SET stock = 'Out of Stock' WHERE quantity = 0;
UPDATE drugs SET stock = 'In Stock' WHERE quantity > 0;
```

Assuming of course the stock field is CHAR or VARCHAR type.

But as I said, it's a bad design. You already have the information about whether something is in stock contained within the value of the quantity field, so use that where you need it instead.

Comment: I am a beginner in PHP and your solution it is work with me >>thanks man

Answer (score 0):

correct sintax for SQL QUERY is

```
SELECT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
WHERE column_name operator value;
```

When you write

```
WHERE quantity
```

it could be you only select those for which quantity different than "0". Just try to select all entries:

```
$select="SELECT * FROM drugs"
```